# Jquery type error, selectors are not working in firefox but working in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a shortlist functionality. I have a dummy div I am cloning that div and putting that div in shortlisted list. This thing was working fine few days back, but today it is not working please help me. Following is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="shortlised-prod1">
    <div class="vis">
        <div class="prod-thumb">
            <img class="short-thumb" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="title-price-wrap">
            <p class="cross"> X</p>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.shortlised-prod1')
    .clone(true)
    .find('img')
    .attr("src", a)
    .end()
    .find('.title-price-wrap a')
    .text(b)
    .attr("ID", id)
    .end()
    .addClass('shortlised-prod')
    .removeClass('shortlised-prod1')
    .insertBefore($('.wrap1'));
```

on load I am using this code. when I load the page, it shows type error at console. It is showing:

```
TypeError: $(...).clone(...).find(...).attr(...).end is not a function
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery? Also, what is "a" and "b" and "id"?

Comment: using these many operations in a single line is not advisable. Break the code into simple lines and that will also help u in debugging the issue

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum JQ is 1.7 and a and b are variables there is no problem in variables.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CPLeg/ works fine in Firefox and Chrome here (also in JQ 1.7), your princess is in another castle, sorry.

Comment: Suggest clearing cache in firefox. Had similar thing with Chrome.

Comment: any idea where should be the error...

Comment: [confirmed, works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/4epLu/)